# Force download and install extension when missing in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I have an Azure DevOps YAML which creates resources on azure with Terraform.
In order to achieve that I have used [this terraform extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.custom-terraform-tasks&targetId=4a805f94-f8ed-49d7-aedf-107f5afe91c7&utm_source=vstsproduct&utm_medium=ExtHubManageList) for Azure DevOps. My goal is to re-use this template in the future on other organizations.

I want to use this YAML template without installing this or any other extension manually.

1. Is there a way to force the YAML to install the extensions that are missing?
2. Is there a way to write a Powershell/any other programming languages to download and install the extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't force download an extension in the YAML :/ but you can use the Rest API [Install Extension By Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/extensionmanagement/installed%20extensions/install%20extension%20by%20name?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to install the extension problematically, with PowerShell for example.

In addition, you can use [Azure DevOps CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/devops/extension?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-azure-devops-az-devops-extension-install) to install the extension.

So you can add a PS task that check if the extension exist, if not - install it.

Or just script that install it and in the first time run the script in the organization.